# SOLVED - Use a nested type to assign values

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am struggling with a typescript typing. I wish to assign a specific type of data according to a nested property. However it seem that Typescript is not able to resolve the proper typing.

I have 2 events inside an enum and a base Event :

```
enum CustomEventType {
    CLICK = 'CLICK',
        WHEEL = 'WHEEL',
}

interface MyCustomEvent< CustomEventType> {
    event: CustomEventType;
}

interface BaseEvent < E = CustomEventType > {
    customEvent: MyCustomEvent < E > ;
    contextData ? : string;
    rawData ? : string;
}
```

In the case of a CLICK event, then I need the contextData and with a WHEEL event, I want to get the rawData.

I attempted something like this :

```
interface ClickEvent extends BaseEvent < CustomEventType.CLICK > {
    customEvent: MyCustomEvent < CustomEventType.CLICK > ;
    contextData: "some context";
}

interface WheelEvent extends BaseEvent < CustomEventType.WHEEL > {
    customEvent: MyCustomEvent < CustomEventType.WHEEL > ;
    rawData: "raw Data";
}

function getEventData(event: ClickEvent | WheelEvent): string {

    if (event.customEvent.event === CustomEventType.CLICK) {
        return event.contextData // string | undefined and I expect it to be defined
    }

    throw new Error("Event is not handled")
}
```

As you can see here on the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQUwdgrgtsDCEGcAuB7KBRAbuJAVAngA4jADeAUMHADICSsA0sALzADksdjbANJcAHUAEunTUW7YaOq9yAX3LkAlmCQgATgDMAhgGMSAWXzxkaLDgA8J1BmyqCxAHxl+IO0gBccRDfP2iIADc8ooqalp6JABC2gggfkgW6BLWZu4OIM4UVLo+aTheRqm2luiOwTkoqiAAHkgAItpI2gD8XsjqKgDmFcDq2gDujc1twB3dwQrK1RH6cAA2SroA1gmgdeAAJgjAMXEJVnkl-sQAdJz0DFn8uabHnsBFRwfFCRnnXFe9ulVqdcPaLwAIgQaBIP2qdSBk1CMx0cwEAAsQCB5mtamowNtdrF4u5Dnc3gFTlIxNccs93IVjJTLK90sTSdRyvx+kMmoDgEC2cAAdCQuRNBAwLokEoqsAuiAkAkAcAABRuAoLJardzAAA+gmRqISAEp2khOmAui5+EpNIr3Kdbr5rUrVCxmKx6Th3hdGHqXFQqOppRB1GBQNaIX8GhzgAB6SNjI3dTXAYWbECaFQgTbAbRYsaIlAQeYZgBGJGTqbA6f4U3NlodSBttNUp1rTpdDbwjJEYi92R9fqQAaDtdObLl0djxtNWqTKbTGazGYQufzRZLM-Lm0r-CQiPUKAGwHL+-Q6l36nlQLWSh2YBQSGAiPn83TQL18iAA) Typescript is not able to resolve the typings.

However if I try with a property at the root of the interface :

```
interface BaseEvent < E = CustomEventType > {
    customEvent: MyCustomEvent < E > ;
    contextData ? : string;
    rawData ? : string;
    eventType: CustomEventType
}

interface ClickEvent extends BaseEvent < CustomEventType.CLICK > {
    customEvent: MyCustomEvent < CustomEventType.CLICK > ;
    eventType: CustomEventType.CLICK;
    contextData: "some context";
}

interface WheelEvent extends BaseEvent < CustomEventType.WHEEL > {
    customEvent: MyCustomEvent < CustomEventType.WHEEL > ;
    eventType: CustomEventType.WHEEL;
    rawData: "raw Data";
}

function getEventData(event: ClickEvent | WheelEvent): string {

    if (event.eventType === CustomEventType.CLICK) {
        return event.contextData // string ok
    }

    if (event.eventType === CustomEventType.WHEEL) {
        return event.rawData // string ok
    }

    throw new Error("Event is not handled")
}
```

The typing is correct. See [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=40&ssc=2&pln=10&pc=1#code/AQUwdgrgtsDCEGcAuB7KBRAbuJAVAngA4jADeAUMHADICSsA0sALzADksdjbANJcAHUAEunTUW7YaOq9yAX3LkAlmCQgATgDMAhgGMSAWXzxkaLDgA8J1BmyqCxAHxl+IO0gBccRDfP2iIADc8ooqalp6JABC2gggfkgW6BLWZu4OIM4UVLo+aTheRqm2luiOwTkoqiAAHkgAItpI2gD8XsjqKgDmFcDq2gDujc1twB3dvW44GV7FCRkhytUR+nAANkq6ANYJoHXgACYIwDFxCVZ5Jf7EAHSc9AxZ-LmmV57ARZfnc+kBd1yPSa-YizL7AkD-B69XRVNR1YbaLwAIgQaBIMOqdSRwQUS3COlWAgAFiAQGtdrU1GAjidYvF3BdXvM-lIxE8cmCCh9jJzVIzfOCbqzqOVXODQUzBcLev0hk1EcAkbLgAjsYtNBAwLokEoqsAuiAkAkEcAABRTVSzDbbXYAH0EJLJCQAlO0kJ0wF0XPwlJpze4bha8AEWMxWD9pn97oxnS4qFR1IaIOowKAAxi4Q15cAAPQ5sbu7rAFBbYD8XFUX3+nCB8Gh8O84O3YWx7LxxNIZOpoM3WUmvMFj1ektlqgV4BIInqFADYBgECz9DqafqU1I3ZKY5gFBIYBE7TUtYgA5I53yIA)

I don't understand why it is not able to resolve that with a nested property. Is it something normal from typescript ? I spent half a day on it and I'm getting lost.

Thanks

There is a hacky way to solve it, it is to use a predicate method :

```
type GetTypeForName<TName, TX = ClickEvent | WheelEvent> = TX extends {
    customEvent: { event: TName };
}
    ? TX
    : never;

// Type predicate to run the narrowing in the outer object based on a nested discriminant
const is = <TName extends BaseEvent["customEvent"]["event"]>(
    x: BaseEvent,
    name: TName
): x is GetTypeForName<TName> => x.customEvent.event === name;

function getEventData(event: ClickEvent | WheelEvent): string {
    if (is(event, CustomEventType.CLICK)) {
        return event.contextData; // string ok
    }

    if (is(event, CustomEventType.CLICK)) {
        return event.rawData; // string ok
    }

    throw new Error("Event is not handled");
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this is a missing feature of TypeScript.  There's no native support for *nested* discriminated unions (feature request at [ms/TS#18758](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18758)).  Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? (Please mention @jcalz to notify me if you reply)

Comment: Thanks @jcalz indeed there is a hacky way to solve the issue. I updated the post.